# Scrolling a div within an iframe (might be jQuery selector issue?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, confluence

Okay, so I'm trying to override the scrollbars on the main browser window so that they instead scroll the contents of the iframe. The problem is, the contents in the iframe itself is stored within a div which seems to be set to be 100% of the containing window (in this case, the iframe).

To make matters more confusing for me, the webpage is actually a confluence page, and the iframe being loaded is also a confluence page, which means the pages have a very deep structure, and have identical ids.

I can use jQuery.

What I have so far (mostly by merging over code found on here..)

```
 var lastScroll = 0;
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     var q = $("#contentBox #splitter-content").scrollTop();
         if (q >= lastScroll){
              q=q+100;
              $("#contentBox #splitter-content").scrollTop(q);
         } else {
              q=q-100;
              $("#contentBox #splitter-content").scrollTop(q);
         }
         lastScroll = q;
 });
```

contentBox is the identifier for the iFrame

I'm not 100% on how jQuery selectors work, but #splitter-content isn't an immediate child of #contentBox. Actually, the structure is more like this:

contentBox -> html -> com-attlassan-confluence -> full-height-container -> splitter -> splitter-container

I think the problem might be that I'm not finding/setting the scrollTop. q is always = 0 after running line 3 of the above code. Which is why I think it may be a selector problem.

Comment: First, iframes are bad. Is there any reason you can't use a simple include macro from confluence? Second, it would help if you could show us the code on the page. My first thought was that you just need to set the div mentioned in your first paragraph to be less than 100% of the page, but maybe that won't work in your context. It would help to see the content you're working with.

Comment: Here's how I would do this, assuming I understand your question right. Insert a div macro to define the size you want your included content to be: http://www.adaptavist.com/display/AtlassianConfluence/div+macro

Comment: and then insert the include page macro inside that div: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Include+Page+Macro

Comment: This way the scroll bars will be included automatically if the content you are including is larger than the div size. Let me know if this solves your problem, and I'll make an answer out of it.

Comment: @MNRSullivan - I can't post much code online, strict company policy. That macro looks interesting, except judging by the language, it can't be used to load external sites? The iframe is used to load multiple internal websites within the company. Think of it like this: Confluence page with navigation bar that controls iFrame. Some of those links on the nav bar are for other confluence pages, some to PDFs, some to other internal web pages.

Comment: the html-include macro can be used to include non confluence pages. You might have to enable it within confluence, but this page links to instructions on how to do so. Also worth noting that while it says the html-include is "dangerous" it's no more dangerous than an iframe. https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/HTML+Include+Macro

Comment: Also, if the PDFs you're including are attached to confluence pages then they can be displayed in a simple include macro. I do so on my company's website quite frequently.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look at it properly tomorrow when I get back to work. If it's not what I need, I'll update the question with more details and try to create a demonstration of my problem as best I can.